# jpg to eps conversion inverts colors

Tags: jpeg, imagemagick-convert, eps, cmyk

I'm trying to convert some CMYK images from jpg to eps using `convert image.jpg -format esp3 image.eps`. The resulting file appears to invert or mangle the color information.

**Sample of the original .jpg:**

[image]

**Sample of the converted .eps:**

[image]

I've tried some variations of the command. The output of `convert -colorspace RGB image.jpg -format esp3 image.eps`, for example, looks significantly better (as in the image is identifiable). Predictably, however, the colors are not correct.

What can I do to correct the outcome? I'm open to other (linux terminal) programs or scripting languages to get the job done.

Potentially useful information:

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me on IM 6.9.10.84 Q16 Mac OSX.

sRGB lena.jpg:

[image]

Convert it to CMYK:

```
convert lena.jpg -colorspace CMYK x1.jpg
```

CMYK lena (x1.jpg):

[image]

Convert to EPS:

```
convert x1.jpg EPS3:x1.eps
```

A display of x1.eps using Mac Preview looks fine - no color inversion.

Likewise, using profiles is even better:

```
convert lena.jpg -profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/sRGB.icc -profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc x2.jpg
```

CMYK lena with profiles (x2.jpg)

[image]

Convert to EPS:

```
convert x2.jpg EPS3:x2.eps
```

Result looks like the jpg from which it was created -- no color inversion.

**Post your input jpg and I can take a look.**

Perhaps it is your version of ImageMagick or of libjpeg or of lcms?

> convert image.jpg -format esp3 image.eps

**Note:** you have *misspelled* -format eps3 (you used esp3). So perhaps the default EPS does not support what you are trying to do.  Also note I prefaced my output with EPS:. Try that, though probably won't matter.

Comment: That messes up the colors. I need to maintain the EPS as CMYK because the images are designed for printing.

Comment: See my addition to my answer.

Comment: Believe it or not, I think it was the misspelling you caught that mucked up the color profile - I'm not sure how. Once I fixed that I got the correct color output.